# How terminate thread reading from socket c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

In c++, "recvfrom" function is a blocking function (block thread till a packet arrive).

How can i safely terminate a thread blocked in "recvfrom" ?

Comment: Set some 'terminate' bool, close the socket from another thread.  If UDP is like TCP, the recvfrom() should return 'early' with an error.

Comment: ..or set the bool and send the socket a UDP message on the local stack, so making it return.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the situation by only calling `recvfrom` once select/poll/epoll has returned successfully.

Like @Remy Lebeau mentioned in the comments you can pullup something like below:

```
while(run_flag) {
    if(check select/poll/epoll) {
         recvfrom(..)
    }
}
```

You can get started with [epoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) and with [select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) here. There is also plenty on the internet.

A different approach would be to use asynchronous networking operations instead of threading.

I might also recommend to use [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) as that will simply all your networking stuff.

Comment: @MartinJames The difference is that he might still want to use the socket, nevertheless I don't know if that works anyway, I actually didn't even know that what you described works with TCP. It sounds interesting but a bit hacky/racy to me.

Comment: @bamboon i what do you mean about "select/poll/epoll" ?

Comment: @bamboon - nah, works fine on TCP Win.  On Linux, every time I've tried it, it's worked, but there has been the occasional 'rumble' that it didn't work on some weird distro or other.  Really, should work OK on any stack worthy of the name.

Comment: @Sub: he is referring to the `select()`, `poll()` and `epoll_create/wait()` functions.  Any one of them can tell you if there is pending data waiting to be read on the socket before you call `recvfrom()`, and all of them have a timeout parameter so your thread can do other things periodically, like check for a termination condition.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - timeout polling - ugh:)

Answer (score 2):

Use the "self pipe" trick.

Open a pipe using the pipe(2) system call. Sit in a loop using select/poll/kqueue/whatever reading from the socket you care about and the pipe. When you get data from your socket, deal with it as you normally would.

To stop the thread, close the other end of the pipe in the thread that wants to stop processing. You will detect this as an EOF on the pipe, which you can then use as a signal to stop the thread processing the real socket.